# Attributing oberservations in overlapping date ranges to months

Tags: python, pandas

I have data that looks like this in a dataframe. The data ranges from 2010-01-01 up until the year 2020 and beyond. This data is on a daily regime but needs to be converted into monthly intervals. The data corresponds to outages (how much of a substance is offline per day) for a given date range.  To do this, I need help breaking down the end points of months so that they span the correct months then I will resample the data using resample('M') in pandas.

I need help transforming this data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'start_date': [datetime(2010,4,3),datetime(2011,4,2), datetime(2011,4,8), datetime(2010,4,24), datetime(2011,5,7)],
    'end_date': [datetime(2010,4,16), datetime(2011,5,1), datetime(2011,5,1), datetime(2010,6,24), datetime(2011,5,16)],
    'duration': [14,30,24,62,10],
    'offline_amount_per_day': [50.0, 50.0, 28.0, 620.0, 21.5]})

    start_date  end_date      duration  offline_amount_per_day
0   2010-04-03 2010-04-16           14   50.000000
1   2011-04-02 2011-05-01           30   50.000000
2   2011-04-08 2011-05-01           24   28.000000
3   2010-04-24 2010-06-24           62  620.000000
4   2011-05-07 2011-05-16           10   21.500000
...
```

into this:

```
     start_date  end_date      duration  offline_amount offline_total
 0   2010-04-03 2010-04-16           14   50.000000        700
 1   2011-04-02 2011-04-30           29   50.000000        1450
 2   2011-05-01 2011-05-01           1    50.000000        50
 3   2011-04-08 2011-04-30           23   28.000000        644
 4   2011-05-01 2011-05-01           1    28.000000        28
 5   2010-04-24 2010-04-30           7    620.000000       4340 
 6   2010-05-01 2010-05-31          31    620.000000       19220
 7   2010-06-01 2010-06-24          24    620.000000       14880
 8   2011-05-07 2011-05-16          10    21.500000        215
```

After this, my plan is to resample the data using df.resample('M') by resampling on the 'start_date' and 'offline_total" columns so that I have an accurate picture of how much of this substance is offline given a month. I want to resample this into all months from 2010-01 to the end of the dataset, throwing out any data that does not fit this range and filling in 0s for months where there is no original daily data.

At the end it should all look like this, where offline_total corresponds to the appropriate integer that should be there:

```
    month      offline_total
0   2010-01          ...
1   2010-02          ...
2   2010-03          ...
...         
3   2014-09          ...
4   2014-10          ...
```

Initially what I tried to do was as follows:

```
duration_offline = duration_offline.set_index('start_date')
duration_offline = df.resample('M')
```

but this did not correctly handle the cases where the months spanned because an index can only be one date. I don't think it is possible to have an index date range. Maybe there is an easier way to do this without so many transformations? I may be overlooking a pandas function.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What does your data actually mean? Something was offline '50' and '28' during the same timespan (index 2 and 3 in your dataframe). Should these be cumulative or averaged?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you probably want duration to be the real difference in days, because in your example above, it is off by one. You can easily do this with pandas like this:

```
df['duration'] = df.end_date - df.start_date
```

Then you can calculate the offline total with a bit of hassle like this:

```
df['offline_total'] = df.duration.apply(lambda x: pd.tslib.Timedelta(x).days) * df.offline_amount_per_day
```

Now you should have something like this:

```
   duration   end_date  offline_amount_per_day start_date  offline_total
0   13 days 2010-04-16                    50.0 2010-04-03          650.0
1   29 days 2011-05-01                    50.0 2011-04-02         1450.0
2   23 days 2011-05-01                    28.0 2011-04-08          644.0
3   61 days 2010-06-24                   620.0 2010-04-24        37820.0
4    9 days 2011-05-16                    21.5 2011-05-07          193.5
```